# readRDS read only some lines

Tags: r, rds

I want to read some files with readRDS. Since these Files are very big I just want to read in several lines of this file. How can I do that ? I tried with nrows =222 but this didn`t work. I get this error:

> Error in readRDS("summarySCC_PM25.rds", nrows = 222) : unused argument (nrows = 222)

This is my code:

```
plot1_x <- function() {   
  library(dplyr)      
  NEI <- readRDS("summarySCC_PM25.rds", nrows =222)
  View(NEI)
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check `?readRDS()`. There is no `nrows` intended, or? Subset `NEI` after reading, e.g. `NEI[1:222, ]`

Comment: This is my problem- I am in the process of devellopping my code and I dont want to read in all of my file every minute - I saw that there is no nrows inteded. if it was I wouldn`have asked

Comment: An RDS file *doesn’t have* rows or lines. It’s a binary format. The argument makes no sense, since it can store arbitrary R objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`readRDS` has no such an functionality, it reads RDS file as a whole.

```
> args(readRDS)
function (file, refhook = NULL) 
NULL
```

If you need 222 rows, you have to make subset after reading, or for development time make extra `RDS` file containing just a necessary fragment.